# Django Rest Framework: docs not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
Django 2.0.1    
DRF 3.7.7
```

I am using automatically generated documentation provided by DRF. My `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API')),
    ...
]
```

This used to work just fine in the past, but recently it stopped working (I don't know why). When I try to access the docs at `http://localhost:8000/docs/`, it gives me the DRF 404 error:

> Error
>
> {'detail': 'Not found.'}
>
> Additional Information Note: You are
>   seeing this message because DEBUG==True.
>
> Seeing this page is usually a configuration error: are your
>   DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES or DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES being
>   applied unexpectedly?
>
> Your response status code is: 404
>
> 401 Unauthorised.
>
> Do you have SessionAuthentication enabled?
>
> Are you
>   logged in?
>
> 403 Forbidden.
>
> Do you have sufficient permissions to access
>   this view?
>
> Is you schema non-empty? (An empty schema will lead to a
>   permission denied error being raised.)
>
> Most commonly the intended
>   solution is to disable authentication and permissions when including
>   the docs urls:
>
> url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='Your API',
>                                       authentication_classes=[],
>                                       permission_classes=[])),
>
> Overriding this template If you wish access to your docs to be
>   authenticated you may override this template at
>   rest_framework/docs/error.html.
>
> The available context is: data the error dict above, request, response
>   and the debug flag.

This is very strange. I have no idea why am I receiving 404 error and there is no additional info... Any suggestion would be super helpful. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have localized the source of this behavior. In one of my API views there is:

```
   def get_serializer_context(self):
       context = super().get_serializer_context()
       context['request'] = self.request
>>>    context['form_id'] = self.kwargs.get('form_id')      <<<
       return context
```

The serializer uses `get_object_or_404` to fetch the correct form, however in the auto-generated docs by DRF there is no `form_id` in `kwargs`. I guess I'll need to refactor this whole thing now...

Comment: Are you logged in? What is your default drf permission class?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm logged in. This is DRF permission classes setting: `'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',)`